# Python: Pass Enum as Argument to another class

Tags: python, enums, constructor, arguments

Iam working on a piece of code, where I use an Enum to define a set of possible values for a property. I want to use it when instancing another class to unambiguously set how it has to be set up. However, it does not work reliably.
I now that there are issues with extending Enums, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Please have a look at the code..:

```
from enum import Enum


class SpecScanParamType(Enum):
    NUM_ACCUMULATIONS = 0
    INTEGRATION_TIME = 1
    LASER_POWER = 2
    AUTOFOCUS = 3
    SPECTRA_BATCH_SIZE = 4


class SpecScanParameter:
    def __init__(self, name: str, paramType: SpecScanParamType):
        self.name: str = name
        self.paramType: SpecScanParamType = paramType


a = SpecScanParameter('test', SpecScanParamType.LASER_POWER)  # works
b = [SpecScanParameter('test', SpecScanParamType.NUM_ACCUMULATIONS),  # works
     SpecScanParameter('nee', SpecScanParamType.SPECTRA_BATCH_SIZE)]  # works

c = [SpecScanParameter('test', SpecScanParamType.INTEGRATION_TIME),  # works
     SpecScanParameter('nee', SpecScanParamType.NUM_ACCUMULATIONS),  # works
     SpecScanParamType('test2', SpecScanParamType.SPECTRA_BATCH_SIZE)]  # DOES NOT WORK????


specScanParameters = [SpecScanParameter('Integration Time (s)', SpecScanParamType.INTEGRATION_TIME),  # works
                      SpecScanParamType('Number of Scans', SpecScanParamType.NUM_ACCUMULATIONS),  # Does not work
                      SpecScanParamType('Spectra Batch Size', SpecScanParamType.SPECTRA_BATCH_SIZE)]  # not reachable...
```

Sooo, the first couple of variations work without issues. However, if I want to create a List of the parameters, it fails in different positions, either when having already one or two in the list.. I cannot recognize any pattern...
Ah, the error raised is this one:

```
TypeError: Cannot extend enumerations
```

So the problem IS somehow related to the extending Enums restriction, but why does it work in some of the cases?
Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated! I really would like to use an Enum at this position, as it makes the code in quite a lot of places much more readable!

Comment: What do you mean “not reachable”? If you add them to a list one at a time, what happens?

Comment: What are you trying to do? On the line labeled `# DOES NOT WORK????` you are creating an instance of `SpecScanParamType` which is why you get this error. Did you mean to create an instance of `SpecScanParameter`?

Answer (score 2):

This may be because you are using `SpecScanParamType` in place of `SpecScanParameter` in some cases.
For example:

```
c = [SpecScanParameter('test', SpecScanParamType.INTEGRATION_TIME),  # works
     SpecScanParameter('nee', SpecScanParamType.NUM_ACCUMULATIONS),  # works
     SpecScanParamType('test2', SpecScanParamType.SPECTRA_BATCH_SIZE)]  # DOES NOT WORK????
```

It seems, it should be :

```
c = [SpecScanParameter('test', SpecScanParamType.INTEGRATION_TIME),  # works
     SpecScanParameter('nee', SpecScanParamType.NUM_ACCUMULATIONS),  # works
     SpecScanParameter('test2', SpecScanParamType.SPECTRA_BATCH_SIZE)]  # works
```

Comment: I am curious to know the reason of down vote. What exactly wrong here?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaah, Oh my god!
Thanks for pointing out the obvious! Argh, classic case of why you just should not work on Sunday evenings....  Thanks man!

(I also have no idea why somebody put  a downvote - your answer could not be any more correct!)

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. They are of no lasting value for the site, they are meant to be closed and deleted. You can flag them with your current reputation, and will be able to vote to close them once you reach 3k rep. A comment under the question for the OP is enough to help him. The problem with answering them is that, if the answer gets upvoted, the question can't be automatically deleted by the system anymore, and manual intervention by several users is requested. So, please help us keep the site clean and useful!